# Mongo can not update 2 values at the same time

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

This Meteor server code tries to update Mongodb collection but gives error:

```js
      let originalDoc = original.fetch()[0];
      Meteor.users.update(userId, {
        $set: {
          profile: originalDoc.profile,
          cmpProfile: originalDoc.cmpProfile,
          aaa: originalDoc.aaa
        },
        $unset: {
          'profile.abc': 1
        }
      });
```

The error:

> Exception while invoking method 'xyz' MongoError: Cannot update 'profile' and 'profile.abc' at the same time

Any ideas? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty self-explanatory: you can't at the same time `$set` whole `profile` and `$unset` `profile.abc` because MongoDB does not allow such operations.

Instead of calling `$unset` you could do `delete originalDoc.profile.abc;` before running query and that will effectively remove `abc` field from `profile` as you're setting whole embedded document.

Comment: delete originalDoc.profile.abc? do you mean $unset originalDoc.profile.abc?  if not, how do I delete it?

Comment: You're setting whole `originalDoc.profile` (i.e. replacing existing one) so if `abc` field will not be present in the object, it won't be in database. Effectively not putting `abc` field will let you get rid of superfluous `$unset` and query will run just fine.